# .Net3.5 Compact Framework filtering binding source

Tags: datagrid, .net-3.5, compact-framework, filtering, bindingsource

I'm trying to get filtering working correctly within a Compact Framework environment.
I'm doing everything manually with code, not the designer.

I have a List. I set this as my datasource to my binding source. I then set my binding source as the datasource of my datagrid.
I apply a bindingSource.filter but it has absolutely no effect.

Am I missing something or is the compact framework just this poor?

I've applied a hard filter here to try to force the filter...

```
            List<Customer> customerList = controller.getCustomersList(selectedDate, view);

            bs.DataSource = customerList;

            customerDataGrid.DataSource = bs;

            bs.Filter = string.Format("Code like '*{0}*'", "123");

            DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
            tableStyle.MappingName = "Customer";

            DataGridTextBoxColumn codeCol = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            codeCol.Width = 125;
            codeCol.MappingName = "Code";
            codeCol.HeaderText = "Code";
            tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(codeCol);

            DataGridTextBoxColumn nameCol = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            nameCol.Width = 265;
            nameCol.MappingName = "Name";
            nameCol.HeaderText = "Name";
            tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(nameCol);

            customerDataGrid.TableStyles.Clear();
            customerDataGrid.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);

            lastView = view;
            lastSelectedDate = selectedDate;
```

Comment: Like only works on strings. Are you using it for an integer?

Comment: String or integer as a string, neither work